# File.Copy - Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, file-copying

I want to copy folder from one place to another. If files and directory exists, I want it to replace them, otherwise it copies files across

Here is the code I have:

```
public void sunfly_num()
{
    if (sunfly378 == true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Karaoke_download_res.locationtoinstall == "")
            {
                pathtoinstall elfenliedpath = new pathtoinstall();
                elfenliedpath.ShowDialog();
                if (File.Exists(locationtoinstall))
                {
                    if(Directory.Exists(Karaoke_download_res.locationtoinstall + "SF378 August 2017"))
                    {
                        File.SetAttributes(locationtoinstall, FileAttributes.Normal);
                        File.Copy(Karaoke_download_res.mainpath + "SF378 August 2017//", Karaoke_download_res.locationtoinstall + "//SF378 August 2017//", true);
                        MessageBox.Show("Path Saved Karaoke Files Added To : " + Karaoke_download_res.locationtoinstall);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      Directory.CreateDirectory(Karaoke_download_res.locationtoinstall + "SF378 August 2017");
                      File.SetAttributes(locationtoinstall, FileAttributes.Normal);           // Makes every read-only file into a RW file (in order to prevent "access denied" error)
                      File.Copy(Karaoke_download_res.mainpath + "SF378 August 2017//", Karaoke_download_res.locationtoinstall + "//SF378 August 2017//", true);
                      MessageBox.Show("Path Saved Karaoke Files Added To : " + Karaoke_download_res.locationtoinstall);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(Karaoke_download_res.locationtoinstall))
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(pathString))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
                    }

                    foreach (var srcPath in Directory.GetFiles(Karaoke_download_res.mainpath + "//SF378 August 2017//"))
                    {
                        //Copy the file from sourcepath and place into mentioned target path, 
                        //Overwrite the file if same file is exist in target path
                        File.Copy(srcPath, srcPath.Replace(Karaoke_download_res.mainpath + "SF378 August 2017//", Karaoke_download_res.locationtoinstall + "\\SF378 August 2017"), true);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Path Saved Karaoke Files Added To : " + Karaoke_download_res.locationtoinstall);
                    //  Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(pathString))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
                    }
                    foreach (var srcPath in Directory.GetFiles(Karaoke_download_res.mainpath + "SF378 August 2017"))
                    {
                        //Copy the file from sourcepath and place into mentioned target path, 
                        //Overwrite the file if same file is exist in target path
                        File.Copy(srcPath, srcPath.Replace(Karaoke_download_res.mainpath + "SF378 August 2017", Karaoke_download_res.locationtoinstall + "SF378 August 2017//"), true);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Path Saved Karaoke Files Added To : " + Karaoke_download_res.locationtoinstall);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception elf)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(elf.Message, "Path Location Error Code: 665");
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug it and run it on the file copy it gives me an error saying

> Access to the path is denied

[image: image of error]

And I'm not sure why its giving me this error. I made sure its run as Administrator. I even tried

```
File.SetAttributes(locationtoinstall, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: `//`? Maybe you meant `\\\`?

Comment: That path in the error looks suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating the source and destination parameters of method `Copy` as common strings. I recommend you to:

1. Use the `Path.Combine()` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to concatenate them;
2. Put the `Combine()` result into a string variable before using it as a parameter for `Copy()` method in order to check what you are using.

Comment: ummm... i never really used path.combine() how would i attempt that ?

Comment: String name = Path.Combine(Karaoke_download_res.mainpath , "SF378 August 2017"),  [Read this for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx)